# Codekit and Libsass: Error: Invalid CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, codekit

so I'm new to SASS and coding in general so please don't be too harsh. I'm self taught.

Anyway, I keep getting this error after using Codekit to compile my html, css, and sass files.

```
Libsass: Error: Invalid CSS after "...blic domain) */": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "*/ {}"
    on line 3 of Users/MargaretBowen/Desktop/Code/better code/_reset.sass
>>    License: none (public domain) */
-----------------------------------^
```

I've been following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDsPH0Zt8Qw#t=3.356712) to help me out. I also tried to use this reset code (https://gist.github.com/hcatlin/1027867) in order to prevent errors from Codekit!

Obviously something isn't going right. Below is what is within my sass file and my _reset.sass file has only the github code in it. Restarting the server within Codekit didn't do anything.

```
// Imports
@import reset
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!! My issue was simply that my file _reset.sass was a Sass file instead of a scss file! Silly error.